# Python-Tkinte r: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, tkinter

I am newly trying to code a GUI based python code for a boolean interpreter
please help me by resolving this error
HERE below is my  of code in python
CODE:

```
def solve():

    strMinterms = app.minterms.get()
    strDontCare = app.dontcare.get()
    strVarNum   = app.varNum.get()
    getLists    = validate(strMinterms,strDontCare,strVarNum)

    if getLists !=False:
        app.min_exp.delete(0,END)
        app.min_imp.delete(0,END)

        answer = minimize(getLists[0],getLists[1],int(strVarNum))
        for i in answer:
            app.min_imp.insert(END,i)
        expr = format_minimized_expression(answer)
        for i in expr:
            app.min_exp.insert(END,i)
        else:
            messagebox.showerror("Bad input","Illegal values, please try again")


class App: 
    def __init__(self, master):
        frame = Frame(master)
        frame.pack(side=LEFT)

        Label(frame,text="variable Number :").grid(row=2,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.varNum = Entry(frame,bg="white")
        self.varNum.grid(row=2,column=1,sticky=W+E)

        Label(frame,text="minterms :").grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.minterms = Entry(frame,bg="white",width=35)
        self.minterms.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky=W)

        Label(frame,text="dontcare :").grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.dontcare = Entry(frame,bg="white",width=35)
        self.dontcare.grid(row=1,column=1,sticky=W)

        Label(frame,text="### Minimized Implicants ###").grid(row=3,column=1,sticky=W+E)
        self.min_imp=Listbox(frame,bg="white",height=8,width=4)
        self.min_imp.grid(row=4,column=1,sticky=W+E)

        Label(frame,text="### Solution ###").grid(row=5,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)
        self.min_exp=Listbox(frame,bg="white",height=8,width=4)
        self.min_exp.grid(row=6,columnspan=2,sticky=W+E)

        self.solve = Button(frame, text="Solve", command=solve)
        self.solve.grid(row=7,columnspan = 2,sticky=W+E)

        self.button = Button(frame, text="QUIT", fg="red", command=frame.quit)
        self.button.grid(row=8,columnspan = 2,sticky=W+E)

root = Tk()
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("Boolean Interpreter")
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

i cant understand the type error in this codelike after compiling my code i do got the widget displayed but  but when i enter values it shows the error like mentioned below:
And now am getting the error like this:

ERROR:

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "C:\Users\Vivek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
>   return self.func(*args)
> File "D:\python\workspace\min\min.py", line 219, in solve
>   answer = minimize(getLists[0],getLists[1],int(strVarNum))
> TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable
> ```

Comment: well apparently your ```validate(strMinterms,strDontCare,strVarNum)``` return ```None``` and you try to do ```getList[0]```.

Comment: will you elaborate  me please i need help

Comment: Is `validate` a function that you defined?

Comment: Yes , and also I have made some changes now 
like:
def solve():
 strVarNum   = app.varNum.get()
    strMinterms = list(map(int,app.minterms.get().split(" ")))
    strDontCare = list(map(int,app.dontcare.get().split(" ")))
    
    
    app.min_exp.delete(0,END)
    app.min_imp.delete(0,END)
    
    answer = min.minimize(strVarNum,strMinterms,strDontCare)
still shows an error like
 unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Please edit question and write a sample of input and expected output, and show `validate` function.

Comment: I can  mail you my total project,will you rectify it

Comment: are you serious ? this is not how it works over here...